# How to force caption title on the left on Latex

Tags: latex, caption, overleaf

I made a `table*`, but the caption title is not at left as I desire.

Does anyone know how to place it at left?

Below is the image:

[image]

Below is the code:

I placed the entire code below including the packages for more details.

I'm using overleaf to run this, but I understand that all latex are the same.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multicol, blindtext, graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{graphicx,float}
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % This is new! Pick from other file


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}

\makeatletter
\def\els@aparagraph[#1]#2{\elsparagraph[#1]{#2}}
\def\els@bparagraph#1{\elsparagraph*{#1}}
\makeatother

\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\caption{Example}
\label{Strings}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2} % for the VERTICAL padding
%\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cccccc} % l - left, c - center, r - right
    \toprule
    \textbf {xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} & \textbf {Example} & \textbf {Name1} & \textbf {Name2} & \textbf {Name3} & \textbf {NameXXXXXXXXXXX}\\ [0,1cm] \hline    
    \makecell[l]{X} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{X}\\  \hline    
    \makecell[l]{X} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{X}\\ \hline    
    \makecell[l]{X} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{} & \makecell[c]{} & \makecell[c]{X}\\ \hline    
    \makecell[l]{X} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{}\\ \hline
    \makecell[l]{X} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{} & \makecell[c]{} & \makecell[c]{X}\\ \hline
    \makecell[l]{X} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{X}\\ \hline
    \makecell[l]{X} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{} & \makecell[c]{} & \makecell[c]{}\\ \hline
    \makecell[l]{X} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{X}\\ \hline
    \makecell[l]{X} & \makecell[c]{AND} & \makecell[c]{} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{X}\\ [0,05cm] \hline
    \makecell[l]{X} & \makecell[c]{OR} & \makecell[c]{} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{X}\\ [0,05cm] \hline
    \makecell[l]{X} & \makecell[c]{OR} & \makecell[c]{} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{X}\\ [0,05cm] \hline
    \makecell[l]{X} & \makecell[c]{} & \makecell[c]{} & \makecell[c]{X} & \makecell[c]{X}\\ [0,05cm] \hline    
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\bigskip\centering
%\end{minipage}
\vspace{-11mm}%Put here to reduce too much white space after your table
\end{table*}%
```

I tried the code above, but did not succeed to place the caption title at left.

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: I attached the image to illustrate what I desire! And also the code.

Comment: Your code can't be compiled. It lacks a class, the necessary packages and a document environment. Your problem depends on the exact geometry of your page. Without the aforementioned information, we can't recreate your problem.

Comment: Hi. I added the beginning, including the packages that I'm using.

Comment: The code in your question does still not compile (missing `\end{document}`). If I fix this, I can't reproduce the image you get https://i.stack.imgur.com/us1Yv.png